# Msg 13607, Level 16, State 4, Line 27

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

i'm pretty new here and i'm trying to parse my JSON but keep getting this error. i have the below query and every time i try running it i get an error, any chance i can get some help? My intended result will be for the data to be displayed on a normal sql grid and later to insert the data into a table with the below formatting.

```
Declare @json varchar(MAX) = '
{"stops": 
            {
                "__type": "stop",
                "__name": "stops",
                "company_id": "xxx",
                "actual_arrival": "20210910130000-0500",
                "actual_departure": "20210910140000-0500",
                "address": "123 noneyabizwax",
                "appt_required": false,
                "city_id": 144537,
                "city_name": "LEWISBURG",
                "state": "TN",
                "zip_code": "37091",
                "confirmed": false,
                "driver_load_unload": "N",
                "eta": "20210910122900-0500",
                "eta_distance": 46,
                "eta_late": false,
                "eta_oor": false,
                "order_id": "12345",
                "planned_arrival_time": "20210910122900-0500",
                "sched_arrive_early": "20210910130000-0500",
                "status": "D",
                "stop_type": "PU"
      }';
select *
from OPENJSON ( @json )             
With (          
            Type Varchar(50) '$stops.__type',
            Name Varchar(50) '$stops.__name',
            CompID Varchar(100) '$stops.company_id' ,
            AcArrvl DATETIME '$stops.actual_arrival' ,
            AcDprtr DATETIME '$stops.actual_departure',
            Addrs Varchar (200) '$stops.address',
            Appt Varchar(50) '$stops.appt_required',
            CityID Varchar(50) '$stops.city_id',
            City Varchar(200) '$stops.city_name',
            State nvarchar(max) '$stops.state',
            Zip int '$stops.zip_code',
            Confirmed Varchar(50) '$stops.confirmed',
            DrvrLd nvarchar(max) '$stops.driver_load_unload',
            ETA DATETIME '$stops.eta',
            ETADISTNC INT '$stops.eta_distance',
            ETALate nvarchar(max) '$stops.eta_late',
            ETAOOR nvarchar(max) '$stops.eta_oor',
            OrderID INT '$stops.order_id',
            PlnndArrvlTm DATETIME '$stops.planned_arrival_time',
            SchdArrvEarly DATETIME '$stops.sched_arrive_early',
            Status nvarchar(max) '$stops.status',
            StopType Varchar(50) '$stops.stop_type',
            [Stops] nvarchar(max) AS JSON
         )
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @json varchar(MAX) = '
{"stops": 
            {
                "__type": "stop",
                "__name": "stops",
                "company_id": "xxx",
                "actual_arrival": "20210910130000-0500",
                "actual_departure": "20210910140000-0500",
                "address": "123 noneyabizwax",
                "appt_required": false,
                "city_id": 144537,
                "city_name": "LEWISBURG",
                "state": "TN",
                "zip_code": "37091",
                "confirmed": false,
                "driver_load_unload": "N",
                "eta": "20210910122900-0500",
                "eta_distance": 46,
                "eta_late": false,
                "eta_oor": false,
                "order_id": "12345",
                "planned_arrival_time": "20210910122900-0500",
                "sched_arrive_early": "20210910130000-0500",
                "status": "D",
                "stop_type": "PU"}
      }';

WITH date_convert 
AS
(
    SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET,STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(JSON_VALUE(@JSON, '$.stops.actual_arrival'),18,0,':'),13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' '),7,0,'-'),5,0,'-')) AcArrvl,
        CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET,STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(JSON_VALUE(@JSON, '$.stops.actual_departure'),18,0,':'),13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' '),7,0,'-'),5,0,'-')) AcDprtr,
        CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET,STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(JSON_VALUE(@JSON, '$.stops.eta'),18,0,':'),13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' '),7,0,'-'),5,0,'-')) ETA,
        CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET,STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(JSON_VALUE(@JSON, '$.stops.planned_arrival_time'),18,0,':'),13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' '),7,0,'-'),5,0,'-')) PlnndArrvlTm,
        CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET,STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(JSON_VALUE(@JSON, '$.stops.sched_arrive_early'),18,0,':'),13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' '),7,0,'-'),5,0,'-')) SchdArrvEarly
)

select Type, Name,CompID,date_convert.AcArrvl,date_convert.AcDprtr,Addrs,Appt,CityID,City,State,Zip,Confirmed,DrvrLd,date_convert.ETA,ETADISTNC,ETALate,ETAOOR,OrderID,date_convert.PlnndArrvlTm,
date_convert.SchdArrvEarly, Status,StopType
from date_convert,
OPENJSON (@json)
With (          
            Type Varchar(50) '$.stops.__type',
            Name Varchar(50) '$.stops.__name',
            CompID Varchar(100) '$.stops.company_id' ,
            Addrs Varchar (200) '$.stops.address',
            Appt Varchar(50) '$.stops.appt_required',
            CityID Varchar(50) '$.stops.city_id',
            City Varchar(200) '$.stops.city_name',
            State nvarchar(max) '$.stops.state',
            Zip int '$.stops.zip_code',
            Confirmed Varchar(50) '$.stops.confirmed',
            DrvrLd nvarchar(max) '$.stops.driver_load_unload',
            ETADISTNC INT '$.stops.eta_distance',
            ETALate nvarchar(max) '$.stops.eta_late',
            ETAOOR nvarchar(max) '$.stops.eta_oor',
            OrderID INT '$.stops.order_id',
            Status nvarchar(max) '$.stops.status',
            StopType Varchar(50) '$.stops.stop_type'
         )
```

It looks a little complicated but I've included an explanation below:

1. Add `}` (curly bracket) at the end of this line `"stop_type": "PU"`
2. You must add `.` (dot) after every `$` sign in your `With` clause.
3. Then we need to remove `[Stops] nvarchar(max) AS JSON` line because you don't need to open another JSON object and also don't forget to remove a `,`(comma) after `StopType Varchar(50) '$.stops.stop_type,'`
4. We need to convert your 5 date strings into at least a partially human readable format. To do this we need to use CONVERT() with STUFF() function. I could have converted all 5 strings in `SELECT` statment but because it would looks ugly I decided to do this in CTE (I named CTE as a `date_convert`)
5. Because we store our converted dates in CTE we don't need them in your `With` clause. So we delete them.
6. In order to see our converted dates with the rest of columns in one table we need to add CTE's name into `FROM` clause. After it's done we have to add name of each column both from your `With` clause and from CTE to `SELECT` statment. The order is not important but I've preserved the order from your original question.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=5b3915d8df86127e1f3c84d0a9880e31

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, your recommendations worked and solved my issue. If i am trying to parse multiple sections of the same json just what different customer data, how should i separate them?

Comment: You want further explanation about how I parsed JSON keys (columns) in your example above? For example why I removed `[Stops] nvarchar(max) AS JSON`?